# authenticate on URL with phantomjs

Tags: java, selenium, authentication, phantomjs

I'm writing some automated tests using Selenium and Java.

The page I am trying to access needs authentication, for chromeDriver I just pass the username and password on the URL like so:

http://USERNAME:PASSWORD@www.mydomain.com

This works fine but with PhantomJS I can't get the page to authenticate so I just end up on about:blank

I've tried adding this to the desired capabilties of the phantomJS driver instance but it still doesn't work:

```
desiredCapabilities.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_CLI_ARGS, new String[] {"--web-security=false", "--ignore-ssl-errors=true", "--ssl-protocol=any", "--proxy-auth=USERNAME:PASSWORD"});
```

Can anyone tell me how to get this working with PhantomJS?

If it matters my password does contain special characters (an @)

**THE ANSWER:::**
I've found out the solution myself but I will leave this here for anyone else that runs into this problem.

It worked fine in ChromeDrive passing in the USERNAME:PASSWORD@DOMAIN on the URL but not in PhantomJS, I tried different way to set the --proxy-auth on the PhantomJS desired capabilties but it wasn't getting beyond the authentication screen.

The solution was simple when I give it the URL with the username and password I just had to encode the @ symbol which was part of my password so I changed @ to %40 and it works fine in ChromeDriver and PhantomJS.

I guess chromeDriver parses the URL to see where the domain start but GhostDriver must just look for the first @ and assume everything after that is the domain.

Comment: You should post the answer as the answer and accept it - this way you will show the question is solved and it will be useful for people later on.

Comment: Thanks @Vaviloff I've added the answer but I can't accept it until tomorrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**THE ANSWER:::**

I've found out the solution myself but I will leave this here for anyone else that runs into this problem.

It worked fine in ChromeDrive passing in the USERNAME:PASSWORD@DOMAIN on the URL but not in PhantomJS, I tried different way to set the --proxy-auth on the PhantomJS desired capabilties but it wasn't getting beyond the authentication screen.

The solution was simple when I give it the URL with the username and password I just had to encode the @ symbol which was part of my password so I changed @ to %40 and it works fine in ChromeDriver and PhantomJS.

I guess chromeDriver parses the URL to see where the domain start but GhostDriver must just look for the first @ and assume everything after that is the domain.